# Extend or go beyond a promise

Tags: word-choice, collocation

Can one fulfill “beyond” a promise? Is it possible to say “extending the fulfillment of a promise”?

I am trying to express that I hope I fulfilled a promise and then some. This is for the acknowledgements of my thesis. I have written: “Many years ago I made a promise to my late maternal grandmother that I would do my best in getting admitted to a university. I hope this effort contributes to fulfilling that promise and beyond just a little bit more.”

Comment: This question is rather vague, and would be much improved if you provided some more details. How would you use such a statement? What sentiment are you trying to convey? What is the context? In its current form, I think this question is likely to accumulate close votes and/or downvotes, so you might want to take another stab at it, and provide some more contextual information.

Comment: In business, a common phrase of this nature is "under promise, over deliver".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JLG's and Billy Moon's answers are spot on. I'd add two things:

- Your thesis does not *contribute* to fulfilling the promise, which was fulfilled before you were admitted; it contributes to fulfilling something else.
- *Fulfill* is a very potent word, and it defeats its potency to employ it in a context where it is merely a stepping stone toward something else. It's like (I date myself) bringing in the Beatles to open for the Monkees. Save it.

I'd go for something more like:

> Many years ago I made a promise to my late maternal grandmother that I would do my best to get admitted to a university. I made good on that promise; I hope this effort justifies her insistence and contributes to fulfilling the larger dream she had for me.

Comment: +1 There might be an emoticon for *standing ovation* but I cannot find it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. The final lines I went with were: "Many years ago I made a promise to my late maternal grandmother that I would do my best to simply get admitted to a university. I hope my current efforts contribute to satisfying further aspirations she may have had for me." It conveys what I wanted to stay a bit more. I think the "I made good on that promise" was a little bit smug since it was obviously given the context. I think adding the "aspirations she may have had for me" arouses more emotion since it brings up a hypothetical. What do you think?

Comment: @Kent  Excellent. *inter alia*, Less is More!

Comment: @StoneyB - Woop Woop!  That rephrased quote ROCKS!

Comment: This is why I love stack exchange - no other forum stimulates a full discussion so well, that always concludes with the best thinking of everyone in the room. This is the right answer. Here here.

Answer (score 16):

An idiom that might suit this situation is that you [*went above and beyond*.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/above+and+beyond)

> *I hope this effort goes above and beyond fulfilling that promise.*

Comment: You hope it *surpasses her expectations* on that promise.

Comment: I was going to suggest this idiom (above and beyond) and "go the extra mile"

Answer (score 9):

Fulfill is an absolute, so can not be extended. You might however, `fulfill a promise, surpassing all expectations`. You might also `more than fulfill` a promise, which in itself implies the promise has been fulfilled.

p.s. congratulations

Comment: Thanks! "surpassing" is the word I was looking for. I wanted to be a little more modest---all part of being a soon to be Dr.! I think I will use: "Many years ago I made a promise to my late maternal grandmother that I would do my best to get admitted into a university. I hope this effort contributes to fulfilling that promise...surpassing the initial expectation slightly." (p.s. would up vote but need a few more reputation points first.)

Comment: If you cannot extend fulfilment, then how can you have "more than fulfilled"?

Comment: I would say that you can fulfill, and then go beyond, like you can fulfill your duties, and then help beyond that. Hard to explain, makes sense to me.